# How can i make month appear with two digits SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, query

how can i make monthid column values appear as  example: 201901, not 20191.

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[table2](accountno, monthid, active)
SELECT accountno, CONCAT(YEAR(InsertionDate), month(insertiondate)), active 
FROM [dbo].[table1]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
DECLARE @t TABLE(InsertionDate datetime);
INSERT @t(InsertionDate) VALUES(GETDATE()), ('20190125');

SELECT CONVERT(char(6), InsertionDate, 112) FROM @t;
```

Result:

```
202004
201901
```

Answer (score 2):

Not sure it is the best way but you could cast the date as a string and then use the "Right" to get only the month like so:

```
declare @date datetime = getdate()
select @date
select MONTH(@date)
select right(CONVERT(varchar(7),@date,102),2)
```

If there is a lot of data, this will not be a performant way to do it. You could create a computed column that will contains the month as a string with the leading 0 for example.